# C# quantlib debug to see the value of class

Tags: c#, quantlib

I am learning the quantlib in c# and someone already use wrapper to do the translate work.
after I run the unit test of inlfation cpi bond(one example of quantlib), I got a wrong output, but not a error.I try to debug the code, but I only can see the value appear as 'quantlib.zerohelper' in Locals when run the debug. Is there any way I could find the value of it?  Thank you

Comment: This seems to be a common problem with C++ libraries exported to C# via SWIG, not one that is specific to QuantLib.  You might try editing the question in that sense (and adding a swig tag) to reach a larger audience that might have experienced the same problem.

Comment: @LuigiBallabio Thx Luigi. I already find the error. I did not update the value for calculating the curve. your code use point to automatically update the value, but c# not. anyway thank you very much